# Is there a retroreflector prism that makes incident and reflected beams collinear?

Tags: optics

I have an application where I need to preserve the angle of incidence of a laser beam. So, I am looking at retroreflector prisms. However, the only ones that I can find translate the incident and reflected beam. In other words, they are parallel, but not collinear. For my application this translation is less than ideal. Is there a way to both preserve the angle of incidence and make the incident and reflected beams overlap?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental characteristic of a corner reflector is that it flips the incoming beam left-for-right and up-for-down. I do not think there is any way to undo that optically while preserving collinearity and parallelism.

Comment: Corner reflectors are normally used at distances where the beam diffusion is larger than the size of a single unit, so effectively, it does return a colinear beam. An array of really little ones would work at smaller scales, like not on the moon scales.